# How can I make an enumerate sublist start at something other than .1?

Tags: lists, enumerate

**I changed the list order**

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}

\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}.}

\begin{enumerate}

\setcounter{enumi}{2}

\item Third item

\end{enumerate}
```

**But I can't change the sublist order**

```
\begin{enumerate}

\setcounter{enumi}{2}

\item Third item

  \begin{enumerate}

  \setcounter{enumi}{3}

  \item item 3.4

  \item item 3.5

  \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}
```

**Is it possible change the sublist order? I need to start the sublist with the item 3.4**

Comment: Any MWE?  Is it an article, a book or what?

Comment: You need `\setcounter{enumii}{3}` in your second code snippet.

Comment: Using `enumitem` this is easy with the `start=3` option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You presumably want

```
\setcounter{enumii}{3}
```

to set the level 2 list, but the `enumitem` package gives a nicer interface to such things.

Answer (score 3):

Using `enumitem`, the `start=...` option can be used. Please note that `enumitem` takes care of the correct value, i.e. if the item should start with `3`, use `start=3`, not `start=2`, i.e. the counter will not increased again.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[start=3]
\item Third item
  \begin{enumerate}[start=4,label*={\arabic*}]

  \item item 3.4

  \item item 3.5

  \end{enumerate}



\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```